# Understand embedded ActiveRecord call in javascript, ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to understand how embedded ActiveRecord call in javascript works. I was working on a project. At one point, it would be helpful to get the id of the last instance I have for a ActiveRecord class. So I have something like this in the javascript:

`<%=Content.last[:id]%>;`

Then I have a dropzone to create new instances of Content, which are also saved.
However, after adding new instance, the value of `<%=Content.last[:id]%>;` does not change even after I refresh the page (I also try go to other page and come back, it't not working). But, I check on my rails console and it's clear the new instances are in the database. After, I test a few times, I found that the value of the code only gets updated when I make changes to the js file.
So how does the ActiveRecord call work in the javascript? Is there a way to make it update itself constantly or whenever it gets called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on where the Javascript file is located. Whenever you see those ERB tags `<%= [something] %>`, keep in mind that they contain *embedded Ruby code* which is executed as soon as the server renders the response. The Javascript file that the browser sees, **doesn't have** any `<%= %>` junk in it; it's been replaced by whatever value the ERB expression printed out. (In this case, it probably printed out the ID number of the last Content object in the database **at the time the page was rendered**.)

You can verify this for yourself: load the relevant page in Chrome, then open up the developer console, find that Javascript file or snippet, and look for that line. The Javascript code isn't executing Ruby code to fetch the latest ID from the database each time the JS code is run; instead, a certain ID number will be hard-coded into it.

So it's important to understand that in a sense, this **isn't really an embedded ActiveRecord call in Javascript**; it's an ActiveRecord call, run on the server, that spits out a value (an ID number), that **just happens** to sit in the middle of a section of Javascript code. The same ActiveRecord call could be run inside one of your `.html.erb` view templates, and it would spit out the number in exactly the same way.

You also ask how to get Javascript to dynamically return the right ID value each time it's run. That's a separate question and basically the answer is, that's what AJAX calls are for. But it's super important for you to understand and play with the above concepts before you can expect to implement AJAX calls in a useful and secure way.

Briefly, an AJAX call means that you set up some Javascript code that, when it's triggered, makes a *separate request* to your server (meaning a new route and a new controller action, and possibly a new view template depending on what content you want to send back to the Javascript code). The server returns a very minimal value (usually in JSON format) which the Javascript code receives and uses to cause some change to the page display.

Comment: Thanks! You explanation is very clear. It helps a lot!